# Client/server architecture

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I am developing an application for ticketing, client checks for a trip and sends via networkstream to the server, then it will return to the client if that trip was found or not, ex: if trip was not found, it shows in the client trip not found, but then if I choose another trip location, and click again on the checktrip button, the client stops working.

Here below, code of check trip in the client:

```
        try
        {

                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);

                sw.WriteLine(comboBox1.Text);
                sw.WriteLine(comboBox2.Text);
                sw.WriteLine(dateTimePicker1.Text);
                sw.WriteLine(dateTimePicker2.Text);

                sw.Flush();
                ns.Flush();
                string x = sr.ReadLine();//freeze point trying abother reservation.
                //MessageBox.Show("Value of x = "+x);
                if (x.Equals("yes"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Trip Found");
                    proceedBtn.Enabled = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Trip Not Found\nPlease Try another");

                }



        }
```

Comment: but, if a trip were in the server, it will return found to the client, then client can proceed to buy a ticket, but if I go back to make another reservation, and click on the above code(inside checktrip button), the client stops working, but doesnt crash. I have tried to put it inside a while(true) method, but nothing.

Comment: code of ticketing inside the server program.

Answer (score 0):

Do you close your streams? What exact error do you encounter?

```
//your try block ends here...
catch(Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}
finally
{
   sr.Close(); sw.Close(); ns.Close();
}
```

**EDIT:** If you close your streams, you should re-create your TcpClient object and Connect again. Or if you don't want to do this, don't close the streams, the connection should be kept alive

Comment: I am closing it, but in another place, inside the button disconnect in the client. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Try to debug it and find out what code causes your client to malfunction.

Comment: Thank you sir, well I put the ns.close() and sw.close() and sr.close() in the finally, it doesn't crash anymore, but its giving me an exception. "The operation is not allowed on non connected-sockets" At System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.GetStream();